# get WithinDistance (rgeos) when I want the distance parameter to vary with the ID in byid

Tags: r, spatial

I may be missing something really simple, but I feel like I ran into weird behavior of gWithinDistance today.

I have two SpatialPointsDataFrames (`cnty_ctr` and `ghcn.s`). The objects can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/preview/UCLA/within_multiple_D.RData?role=personal

I'm trying to identify which features in `ghcn.s` are within a distance of each point in `cnty_ctr`. The catch is that I'd like the within distance to be specific to each point in `cnty_ctr` (`cnty_ctr$RADIUS2` to be specific). I've tried this:

```
stn.r2 <- gWithinDistance(cnty_ctr, ghcn.s, dist = cnty_ctr$RADIUS2, byid = TRUE)
```

but I get several more TRUE than I should.

```
#i.e. I get this:               #when I should get this (only column 111 shown):

              067   083   111                 111
USC00040232  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USC00041912  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USC00043134  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USC00044712  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USC00047646  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USW00023232  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USW00023271  TRUE FALSE FALSE               FALSE
USC00041253 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USC00043402 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USC00046154 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE               FALSE
USC00047681 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USC00047902 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE               FALSE
USC00049111 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USW00023190 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USW00023273 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USW00093209 FALSE  TRUE FALSE               FALSE
USC00042941 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
USC00044422 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USC00046399 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USC00046602 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
USC00046940 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USC00048014 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
USW00003159 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
USW00023129 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
USW00023136 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USW00023187 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USW00093111 FALSE FALSE  TRUE                TRUE
USW00093134 FALSE FALSE  TRUE               FALSE
```

It seems that this is because gWithinDistance doesn't accept a vector. And is using some value of the vector as the search distance (the distances for the false positives are greater than the $RADIUS2 value). Any idea of what I can use instead?

Comment: Can you provide your sample-data using `dput`? This makes it easier for other user to read your data into a R-session.

Comment: I used `save` to output the objects and uploaded them to dropbox. I edited my question to include the link to the objects. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the work around I came up with:

```
stn.r2 <-  lapply(seq_len(length(cnty_ctr@data$RADIUS2)), 
              function(i) gWithinDistance(cnty_ctr, ghcn.s, dist = cnty_ctr$RADIUS2[i], byid = T))
names(stn.r2) <- cnty_ctr@data$COUNTYFP
```

it's not as easy to read/intuitive as I was hoping for, but it gets the job done.